# Synchronous pattern matching algorithm for multiple concatenated strings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

For a class subject, I must implement a class that looks for a pattern in a set of chars that the class receives in a chronological order. Each character the class receives has a particular source (a planete, identified by an int ID).

We have to implement the data structure ourselves, and so I implemented a String List where I store all these characters in a chronological order.

The problem is that the pattern must be matched for characters coming from the same planete (source), so pattern matching must be made on each source.

I tried to use famous pattern matching algorithms like Rabin Karp by browsing the whole list and only taking into account the currently browsed source, and then doing this for all the sources, but the performances are really lame, even worse than a naive (but synchronous) solution.

Do you have any idea about which algorithm could be more efficient in that case ? (letting me use each character I'm browsing, even if this implies storing the actual "search state" of that source somewhere, like we did for the naive implementation)

P.S: The IDs are finite (from 1 to 128) but the number of chars can go up to 10⁷

**EDIT:** Here are some details that will hopefully clarify things.

`IntlFinder`, my class,can receive characters (or array of characters) by a method `Add(char* pszData, int nSource)`; Hence, each character is coupled with a Source ID. The pair (character, source) is stored in a StringList `ComList` (in chronological order of their addition).

For the pattern to be present in my class, it must be present for THE SAME SOURCE.

Example:

If I'm looking for the pattern SAYKOUK

(**S**, 1); (**A**, 1); (**Y**, 1); (**K**, 1); (Z, 2); (S, 3); (**O**, 1); (**U**, 1); (**K**, 1) 
is OK !

(**S**, 1); (**A**, 1); (**Y**, 1); (K, 2); (O, 3); (U, 1); (K, 4) 
is not OK.

This is problametic because if I only consider one source (ranging from 1 to 128) and browse the whole list each time, my pattern searching method is *REALLY* slow. And I can't manage with any of these algorithms to take into account the characters of the different sources and know whenever I met my pattern with any of them !

Comment: So far I don't see how this is different from matching each string separately. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you intend here. Just, with short demo string, obviously?

Comment: Can you elaborate more with some example or paste code snippets that would clarify the issue more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a linked list with the classical "next" and "previous" pointers but also "nextSource" and "previousSource" that points to the characters of the same source. That way, I was able to use classical pattern-matching algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to store a separate list of characters for each source, then find the pattern in these lists separately.

Comment: The problem is I need to know the position of the first character of the pattern in my list... And I don't want to store characters positions in a list where the index already represents the position.

(+ I forgot to say it, but I don't always start my search from 0. I can start it from another index)

Comment: Today, you store the source index in the list. Instead you could store a separate array that tracks which source index corresponds to which stream index. There should be not be more memory used if the indices are of the same datatype.

Comment: @halflings It sounds like you can just use this solution and use a well-known pattern-matching algorithm on the applicable list.

Comment: The problem is that I need to keep track of the chronological order of reception of each character.

I ended up using a linked list with another type of pointers included : a pointer to the next char of the same source; By using this, I was able to use traditional pattern-matching algorithms. I'll add this answer right now. Thank you !